# Dúvidas com File Upload

Tags: javascript, plugin, file-upload

Minha dúvida é em relação a Upload de Arquivos utilizando o http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input

Tenho o seguinte código JS

```
$('#arquivoCliente').fileinput({
            language: 'pt-BR',
            uploadAsync: false,
            showPreview: false,
            maxFileSize: 200,
            uploadUrl: 'upload.php',
            allowedFileExtensions : ['PDF', 'pdf']
            uploadExtraData: function() {
                return {
                    id: tempIDCliente
                };
            }
        });
```

O meu php está todo ok, está salvando o arquivo e tudo mais. O que não consigo fazer é. 
Como podem ver o meu código está setado para aceitar somente a extensão PDF.
Caso o usuário escolha outra extensão, o botão de envio fica desativado.

Porém esta opção só está funcionando se eu comentar a linha uploadUrl, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
$('#arquivoCliente').fileinput({
            language: 'pt-BR',
            uploadAsync: false,
            showPreview: false,
            maxFileSize: 200,
            // uploadUrl: 'upload.php',
            allowedFileExtensions : ['PDF', 'pdf']
            uploadExtraData: function() {
                return {
                    id: tempIDCliente
                };
            }
        });
```

Não comentado fica assim
[image: Não comentado]

Comentado assim
[image: Comentado]

Comment: Mas o que pretende? Só lembrando que o Javascript desse plugin funciona assim!

Comment: Oi @VirgilioNovic fiz o seguinte, desabilitei no fileuploaderror, 

            $('#arquivoCliente').on('fileuploaderror', function(event, data, msg) {
                var form = data.form, files = data.files, extra = data.extra,
                    response = data.response, reader = data.reader;
                console.log('File upload error');
               // get message
               alerta(msg, 'danger');
               $('.fileinput-upload-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }); 

Seria essa a melhor forma?

Comment: Então você conseguiu resolver? se sim coloque como resposta!

Comment: Na verdade não sei se é assim. Funcionou, mas não sei se isso foi uma grande gambiarra.

Comment: Talvez não seja guambiarra, talvez seja bug mesmo e isso contornou!

Comment: Se ele tiver repositorio no github talvez abrir um issue e dizer a eles o problema é uma boa! https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput

Comment: Vou colocar minha resolução como resposta aqui e fazer isso.

Comment: Obrigado @VirgilioNovic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é o correto, mas consegui contornar da seguinte maneira.

```
$('#arquivoCliente').fileinput({
            language: 'pt-BR',
            uploadAsync: true,
            showPreview: false,
            maxFileSize: 200,
            uploadUrl: 'upload.php',
            allowedFileExtensions : ['PDF', 'pdf'],
            uploadExtraData: function() {
                return {
                    id: tempIDCliente
                };
            }
        });

        $('#arquivoCliente').on('fileuploaded', function(event, data, previewId, index) {
            var form = data.form, files = data.files, extra = data.extra,
                response = data.response, reader = data.reader;
            console.log('File uploaded triggered');
            $('#arquivoCliente').fileinput('clear'); // Essas três linhas uso para atualizar o campo após o update
            $('#arquivoCliente').fileinput('refresh');
            $('#arquivoCliente').fileinput('enable');


        });

        //aqui testa se o arquivo é PDF e dentro do tamanho máximo estipulado

        $('#arquivoCliente').on('fileuploaderror', function(event, data, msg) {
            var form = data.form, files = data.files, extra = data.extra,
                response = data.response, reader = data.reader;
            console.log('File upload error');
           alerta(msg, 'danger');
           $('.fileinput-upload-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // Desabilito o botão de upload manualmente
        });
```